# How Windows message pump works internally?

Tags: windows, message, message-queue

Lets take most primitive example of Windows application possible:

```
MSG msg;
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Let's also assume that there is `WindowProc` callback function somewhere in the program's code that processes some messages (the `WindowProc` itself is not very important for this question).

Now, what I can't understand and visualise is how `GetMessage` (or `PeekMessage`) manages to do what it does internally. I mean, how can it suspend the calling thread until some messages come, then execute the message and continue to block it.

Lets say the message queue is full with some messages, and `GetMessage` is in the process of retrieving and dispatching them:

[image]

But at this moment, some nonqueued message suddenly arrives:

[image]

What happens to the queue? What if one of the queue messages was in the middle of being dispatched?

How nonqueued message is even processed if the body of the `while` loop is not executed, `DsipatchMessage` is not executed for nonqueued messages also.

What happens if yet **another** nonqueued message comes along while 1st is still not dispatched? It cannot be added to queue and left for later.

How in a world this system is possible to implement? With some kind of semaphore/mutex/events? Can anybody explain this to me and give a simple example of implementation of this system? Preferably with some graphical visualisations, please.

Ultimately, the gist of this question: Why `GetMessage` is still needs to be called to receive nonqueued `SendMessage` message, when it supposed to directly call `WinProc` without using the queue at all?

Comment: When you say "nonqueued message" are you talking about the difference between SendMessage and PostMessage?

Comment: Messages go through the OS.  The OS is free to keep additional queues for PostMessage or anything else.  Have you done a search on something like "windows internals message queue" ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, nonqueued means that some other process called `SendMessage` and it will only return when our example program handles it.

Comment: @HansPassant Check out the answer that I created. Is it close to truth? How do you reckon?

Answer (score 0):

So, after not receiving any answers to this gruelling question I decided to came up with my own educated guess. So this is how Windows message queue might function inside:

```
Assume              0x00                                        0x00
Physical            0x01 Other system functions...              0x01 Other system functions...
Memory adresses     0x02                                        0x02                                      JUMP
                    0x03                                        0x03                                      FROM
GetMessage() BEG--> 0x04 -------------------------              0x04 -------------------------      <<<<< SendMessage()
is consumer         0x05 if ( nonqueue_flag == true )           0x05 if ( nonqueue_flag == true )     
                    0x06    WaitForMutex(msg_processing_lock);  0x06    WaitForMutex(msg_processing_lock);
PostMessage()       0x07    res = WindowProc();                 0x07    res = WindowProc();               
is producer         0x08    ReleaseMutex(msg_processing_lock);  0x08    ReleaseMutex(msg_processing_lock);
                    0x09    return res;                         0x09    return res;                       
WM_QUIT             0x0A                                        0x0A                                      
is signaled         0x0B if ( quit_flag == true )               0x0B if ( quit_flag == true )             
not sent in a msg   0x0C    return 0;                           0x0C    return 0;                         
                    0x0D                                        0x0D                                      
                    0x0E WaitForSemaphore(queue_empty_count)    0x0E WaitForSemaphore(queue_fill_count)   
                    0x0F                                        0x0F                                      
                    0x10 WaitForMutex(msg_processing_lock);     0x10 WaitForMutex(msg_processing_lock);   
                    0x11 *msg = PopQueue();                     0x11 *msg = PopQueue();                   
                    0x12 ReleaseMutex(msg_processing_lock);     0x12 ReleaseMutex(msg_processing_lock);   
                    0x13                                        0x13                                      
                    0x14 ReleaseSemaphore(queue_empty_count);   0x14 ReleaseSemaphore(queue_fill_count);  
                    0x15 return 1;                              0x15 return 1;                            
GetMessage() END--> 0x16 -------------------------              0x16 -------------------------
                    0x17                                        0x17
queue_empty_count:  0x18                                        0x18
Num. of free        0x19                                        0x19
spaces in queue     0x1A Other system functions...              0x1A Other system functions...
                    0x1B                                        0x1B
                    0x1C                                        0x1C
                    0x1D                                        0x1D
                    ORIGINAL WINDOW THREAD                      OUTSIDE PROCESS THREAD
```

So how does `SendMessage()` from another process gets executed?

```
WT  - window's thread
OPT - outside process' thread
```

1. Using `HWND` passed by `OPT` to `SendMessage()` OS finds window's class declaration
2. OS extracts `threadID` of the thread that spawned the window (`WT`)
3. OS fills the *secret* global flags and other internal values to be mostly the same as the `WT` except the `nonqueue_flag`, which is set to `TRUE`
4. OS calls `GetMessage()` from `SendMessage()` (remember, both `WT` and `OPT` use the same `GetMessage()` code)
5. Now, if `WT` is still processing some queued messages, `OPT` waits on a Mutex (**0x06**)
6. As soon as the last queue message was dispatched to `WT`, `OPT` claims the Mutex and calls `WT`'s `WindowProc()` function. If there are any other messages on the queue, `WT` will wait on the same Mutex (**0x10**) until the nonqueued message is handled
7. After returning from `WindowProc()`, `OPT` releases the Mutex (**0x08**) and returns the value back to `OPT`'s code
8. At this point, `WT` will continue to pop queue messages if present, or just wait on Semaphore (**0x0E**) if the queue is empty (`queue_empty_count == MAX_QUEUE_SIZE`)
9. After this the process repeats indefinitely, unless the `WM_QUIT` massage was posted to the queue, which is technically not true, as the `WM_QUIT` message is not posted but signalled by some hidden global boolean value when `PostQuitMessage()` is called by the `WT`.

Queue itself is implemented in the form of Doubly Linked List internally, but I'm not sure. Might be just an array?

So that's that. I hope this guess is as close to the true implementation as possible. I would very much like to see the glimpse of it myself. Would be cool if [@Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) could look into this to confirm/debunk my guess.